# Term for area affected by/endangered by a wildfire

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, lexicon

Is there a conventional term (regardless of its level of formality) referring to the area which is (currently) affected by and/or endangered by a [wildfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildfire)? — a roughly analogous term in the case of a tornado would be the areas *in the path of the tornado*<sup>†</sup>.

---

<sup>†</sup>I don't know of a more concise term for this, either, but this seems to be a fairly fixed expression.

Comment: *Footprint*, perhaps? I don't know if there's a technical term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Fire perimeter](https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/fire-perimeters-current)*** is the expression generally used to refer to the area affected by a fire:

> - ***Wildfire perimeters for the current fire season***, including both active and inactive fires, supplied from various sources. The data is refreshed from operational systems nightly. These perimeters are rolled over to Historical Fire Polygons on April 1 of each year.

(catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca)

[image] 
From (akfireinfo.files.wordpress.com)